# Irrational REGEX Pattern Matching in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

```
guest@porteus:~$ [[ "libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4" =~ ^.*[.]so(([.][0-9]+)+)*$ ]] && echo LIB
LIB
guest@porteus:~$ echo ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
3
guest@porteus:~$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
.0.8.4
guest@porteus:~$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
.4
```

Regex works and library version can be retrieved.

```
guest@porteus:~$ [[ "libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4" =~ ^.*[.]so(([.][0-9]+)+)*$|^lib.+[.]so.* ]] && echo LIB
LIB
guest@porteus:~$ echo ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
3
guest@porteus:~$ echo "'${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
''
guest@porteus:~$ echo "'${BASH_REMATCH[2]}'"
''
```

Matches, but version irretrievable.

```
guest@porteus:~$ [[ "libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4" =~ ^.*[.]so(([.][0-9]+)+)*$|^lib.+[.]so(.*) ]] && echo LIB
LIB
guest@porteus:~$ echo ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
4
guest@porteus:~$ echo "'${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
''
guest@porteus:~$ echo "'${BASH_REMATCH[2]}'"
''
guest@porteus:~$ echo "'${BASH_REMATCH[3]}'"
'.0.8.4'
```

Version now only retrievable from alternative regex match.

The question is why the first match is ignored, and is there any way of telling when an alternative will be matched out of sequence?

Comment: It works as you seem to expect for me in bash 3.2.48 (on OS X), but not 4.2.37 (on Debian).

Comment: works on osx in `4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)` (macports) also in `4.3.33(0)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd9.0)`.

Comment: OT: I don't understand the `*` in `(([.][0-9]+)+)*`. What it applies to is already repeated, so all that `*` does is make it optional. But then you could have just used an optional repeat in the first place: `(([.][0-9]+)*)`. I don't think that affects the way the alternation is matched (although you never know), but it's always a good idea to avoid pointless repetition operators.

Comment: @ rici Well spotted. Don't know how the * crept in, as wanted anyway to end in '. numeric', and not have a '.*' at the end. Took star out, reran test, no change in described behaviour. This for Slackware bash 4.2.053-1. Also the same for bash 4.2-5ubuntu3 i386.

Comment: @bogomips: Yeah, I didn't think it would make a difference. The fact that there is different behaviour on MacOSX/FreeBSD and Linux probably stems from the fact that the MacOSX C library was (the last time I looked) still using Henry Spencer's venerable regex implementation, while the GNU libc has grown something else. Both are supposed to conform to the Posix standard.

Answer (score 1):

Posix does not specify any preference between the patterns in an alternation (i.e. a regex pattern with <kbd>|</kbd> as its main operator.)

Posix requires:

- that the overall match be the longest of the possible matches starting at the leftmost position at which a match is possible.
- that each subpattern, from left to right, be as long as possible, within the remaining possibilities.

This is quite different from (traditional) Perl and ECMAscript, which require that alternations be tried in order and that the success of an alternative is preferred over following alternatives, even if the following alternatives would be longer.

These are just two ways of defining regular expression matching. I don't think either is more "rational"; there are good arguments for and against each, and ultimately one needs to be chosen.

The Posix model is closer to the mathematical model for regular languages, for what it is worth.

If both alternatives in an alternation match the same string, one must be chosen. It is up to the implementation to decide which, and since it is unspecified, it might change from version to version.

Your best bet is to allow either capture to be used. Eg (using your third example):

```
version=${BASH_REMATCH[2]:-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `bash` itself doesn't specify what regular expressions it uses. Instead, `=~` uses whatever the underlying system's regular expression library.

Comment: @chepner: the bash manual says "the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex3))". I don't see a way of interpreting that reference to EREs with a link to a posix manpage in any other way than that they are posix regexes.

Comment: It's a technicality, but the fact remains that `bash` does not ship with its own regular expression engine, and is dependent on the OS to provide it. `bash` itself cannot absolutely guarantee portable behavior. (Yes, I'm probably being overly pedantic.)

Comment: @chepner: bash does not ship with its own C library at all, and it depends on the parts that it uses to have Posix semantics. If it cannot find `regexec` and `regcomp`, it will disable regular expressions. (The build config option is even documented as enabling "Posix regular expressions", see section 10.8 of the bash manual.) So it clearly specifies the *intent*. (If you compile it in an environment which uses Posix library names with non-Posix implementations, the Behaviour is Undefined.) Given the clearly identified intent, the bash user should be prepared for Posix regex matching. No?